# When was the parity of a permutation first understood?

Tags: combinatorics

In combinatorics, it is well understood that [a permutation has a parity or sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation): each permutation is either *odd* or *even* (sometimes described as *negative* and *positive*, respectively).  Composing two permutations of the same parity yields an even permutation; composing two of opposite parity produces an odd parity result.

I am trying to establish *when* this concept was first understood, regardless of whether the word *parity* was used to describe it.  I vaguely recall reading that Pascal (1623–62) was one of the first to talk about it, but I cannot now find a source for this and am doubting my memory.  I'm feel certain Euler (1707–83) must have understood this, but my Latin is not up to reading [*Institutiones Calculi Differentialis*](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_sYE_AAAAcAAJ/) to confirm.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure Pascal or Euler dealt with parity specifically? The enumerative problems they considered were not suggestive of it and they lacked means to distinguish even from odd. Histories of group theory, e.g. [Kleiner's](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690312), do not mention either of them. [Batlow's Historical Note on the Parity of Permutations](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2316272) suggests that the earliest observation come from Vandermonde (effect on the alternating polynomial) and the earliest proof is due to Cauchy (1815), who used disjoint cycles.

Comment: @Conifold – no, not at all sure.  I'm rather sceptical that Pascal did and think it's more likely that my memory is faulty.  With Euler, perhaps I'm thinking about his work on polynomials in too modern a way.  Thanks for the link to Bartlow's paper.